# Java remove duplicate Object properties

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, lombok

I'm trying to return a `List<Object>` with no duplicate properties (using `CSVRecord`).

I received a CSV like this one:

```
brand;color
bmw;red
bmw;blue
jaguar;yellow
jaguar;red
mercedes;bleu
fiat;green
```

Car class look like (for example):

```java
@Builder
@Data
public class Car {

  private String brand;
  private List<String> color;

}
```

I've a method like this (just for example):

```java
public List<Car> convert(List<CSVRecord> csvRecordList) {
    Map<Car, List<CSVRecord>> csvRecordsByCar = csvRecordList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(csvRecord -> Car.builder()
            .brand(csvRecord.get("brand"))
            .color(Collections.singletonList(csvRecord.get("color")))
            .build()
        ));

    return csvRecordsByCar .entrySet().stream()
        .map((Map.Entry<Car, List<CSVRecord>> csvRecordByCar) ->
            Car.builder()
                .brand(csvRecordByCar.getKey().getBrand())
                .color(csvRecordByCar.getKey().getColor())
                .build()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

For now it's returning me a `Car` list object with duplicates brand. what I'd like is not to have duplicate brand and merge brand's color in a list, like:

```java
Car{
  brand: "bmw",
  color: ["red", "blue"]
}
```

I'm pretty new in java.

Comment: Can you share your car class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `Car` object after the grouping. Currently, since you are grouping by the `Car` object itself, there would be a `Car` object for each combination of `brand-color` in the resultant list. First you need to just group by color and then proceed with object creation.

**Note:** Assume static import of `Collectors` methods `toList()`, `mapping()` and `groupingBy()` in the below code.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map 
    = csvRecordList.stream()
                   .collect(groupingBy(record -> record.get("brand"),
                                       mapping(record -> record.get("color"), 
                                               toList())));

// Now convert this map to list of Cars
return map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(entry -> Car.builder()
                           .brand(entry.getKey())
                           .color(entry.getValue())
                           .build())
          .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the car class, I'd assume from the first part of the function is that you are `groupingBy` `Car` which relies on you implementing `equals` and `hashcode`.

So that is probably why you are getting duplicates like

```
Car{
  brand: "bmw",
  color: ["red"]
}

Car{
  brand: "bmw",
  color: ["blue"]
}
```

The another option to consider is `groupBy` `brand` name and collect a list of `color`s then map that result into your List of `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your car class has colors as list making the class look like below:

```
public class Car {
private String name;
private List<String> color;
}
```

You need to add the following method in your car class,

```
public void addColor(String color){
    if(null==this.color){
        this.color = new ArrayList<>();
    } 
   this.color.add(color);
}
```

and try this:

```
    public List<Car> convert(List<CSVRecord> csvRecordList) {
Map<String, List<CSVRecord>> csvRecordsByCar = csvRecordList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(csvRecord -> csvRecord.get("brand")));

List<Car> result= new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry mapElement : csvRecordsByCar.entrySet()) {
        String key = (String)mapElement.getKey();
        List<CSVRecord> value = (List<CSVRecord>) mapElement.getValue();
        Car car=new Car();
        car.setName(key);
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord2 : value) {
            car.addColor(csvRecord2.get("color"));
        }
        result.add(car);
    }
     return result;
    }
```

Comment: it's removing the duplicates keys, but with their values too

Comment: Have you added the addColor method to your POJO?

Comment: yes i did as you write it

Comment: I have tried this in my local...it is working fine check if you are missing anything else

Comment: `this.color.add(color);` part in the `addColor` method could be moved outside the `if` condition as it has to be done always.

Comment: @GauthamM Thanks for pointing it Gautham, I have updated my answer.